# hitTest:withEvent: Not Working

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm making an app where I have a background view and that has six `UIImageView`'s as subviews.  I have a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to see when one of the `UIImageView`s is tapped on and thie handleTap method below is what the gesture recognizer calls.  However, when I run this, the `hitTest:withEvent:` always returns the background view even when I tap on one of the imageViews.  Does it have something to do with the event when I call hitTest?

Thanks

```
- (void) handleTap: (UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender
{
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        CGPoint location = [sender locationInView: sender.view];
        UIView * viewHit = [sender.view hitTest:location withEvent:NULL];
        NSLog(@"%@", [viewHit class]);
        if (viewHit == sender.view) {}
        else if ([viewHit isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
        {
            [self imageViewTapped: viewHit];
            NSLog(@"ImageViewTapped!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

UIImageView are, by default, configured to not register user interaction.

From the UIImageView documentation:

> New image view objects are configured to disregard user events by
>   default. If you want to handle events in a custom subclass of
>   UIImageView, you must explicitly change the value of the
>   userInteractionEnabled property to YES after initializing the object.

So, right after you initialize your views you should have:

```
view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

This will turn the interaction back on and you should be able to register touch events.

Answer (score 1):

There's a rewrite on your approach (single GR on the containing view) that works, but it'll make our brain hurt getting the coordinate systems right, which is definitely the problem in the posted code.

The better answer is to attach N gesture recognizers to each of the UIImageViews.  They can all have the same target and use the same handleTap: method.  The handleTap: can get the view without searching any geometry like this:

```
UIImageView *viewHit = (UIImageView *)sender.view;
```

Comment: Ah well the project is almost done and the whole project uses the code snippet given but maybe later when I have it working I'll try this.  Thanks anyway.